# Django website running too slow on Google Cloud Platform(GCP)

Tags: django, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apache2

I am planning to migrated from DigitalOcean(DO) to Google Cloud(GCP).

I have taken trial on GCP and hosted Django website on it, but it is running too slow (it take 12-15 seconds to open page). Same website running on DO is very fast(it take hardly 1 second to open page).

Website is hosted on Ubuntu 20 LTS (on DO & GCP) & Apache2 server

On GCP there is no user right now, for testing I am only one user and it is running too slow. I have 2CPU and 8GB memory on VM.

I am not able to find out the issue why it is running slow on GCP and running fast on DO?

Can someone please help to find out solution?

Comment: Can you provide more information and also are you deploying the Django application in App engine or Compute engine?

Comment: I am deploying on Ubuntu 20.0 VM. My website developed in django 3.1

Answer (score 0):

When comparing Google Cloud Platform performance with the local one you should keep in mind that deploying on GCP needs more time to import all the necessary libraries and set up the Django framework.

In general it doesn't make much sense to compare the performance on your local machine with the performance on GCE, as local machines are likely running a different OS than GCE

In addition to that there are various ways to optimize your application’s performance, as the following typical ones:
[Scaling configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#scaling_elements), by setting up “min_idle_instances” to be kept running and ready to serve traffic.
Using [Warm Up Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests) to reduce request and response latency during when your app's code is being loaded to a newly created instance.

I came across [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) Insights, which analyzes the content of a web page, then generates suggestions to make that page faster and could be handy